# Is something like "typedef int arrChoice[5];" a global variable?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, global

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
typedef arrChoice[10] /*is this a global variable?*/
int main() {};

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

its not done yet, but this is what i meant.

Comment: typedef is not a variable, it just does what it says...defines a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typedef is not a global variable, it's simply an alias for another type. I usually use them for function pointers when I'm passing those around because writing them out every time is annoying.

`typedef int (*function)(int, int);`

I also use them to define a structure, union, or enumeration as a type

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} Point;
```

Answer (score 0):

typedef declares the new type not variable.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. In the code you posted here, there is a error. There are no statements in side main function. getch and return statements should be inside main function. I feel your code should be like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int  arrChoice; /* arrChoice is alias to int */
arrChoice a[10] ;/* array a is a global variable of integers*/
int main()
{
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

please note that the purpose of typedef is to assign alternative names to existing types(int,float,double,etc.).  The following statements are similar.

```
typedef arrChoice[10]  is similar to typedef int[10];
```

When you try to refer arrChoice, then you get an error message

```
expected expression before 'arrChoice'.
```